# Debian 7 - Update gitlab-shell to 1.9.6 from 1.9.5

Tags: debian, gitlab

I'm setting up a Gitlab on a Debian Server 7.6

When executing this:

```
# bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production
```

Output:

```
Instance method "lock!" is already defined in ActiveRecord::Base, use generic helper instead or set StateMachine::Machine.ignore_method_conflicts = true.
 Warning 
  You are running as user root, we hope you know what you are doing.
  Things may work/fail for the wrong reasons.
  For correct results you should run this as user git.

Checking Environment ...

Git configured for git user? ... no
  Try fixing it:
  sudo -u git -H git config --global user.name  "GitLab"
  sudo -u git -H git config --global user.email "admin@gitlab.wiserobot"
  For more information see:
  doc/install/installation.md in section "GitLab"
  Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.

Checking Environment ... Finished

Checking GitLab Shell ...

GitLab Shell version >= 1.9.6 ? ... FAIL. Please update gitlab-shell to 1.9.6 from 1.9.5

Checking Sidekiq ...

Running? ... no
  Try fixing it:
  sudo -u git -H RAILS_ENV=production bin/background_jobs start
  For more information see:
  doc/install/installation.md in section "Install Init Script"
  see log/sidekiq.log for possible errors
  Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.

Checking Sidekiq ... Finished

Checking LDAP ...

LDAP is disabled in config/gitlab.yml

Checking LDAP ... Finished

Checking GitLab ...

Database config exists? ... yes
Database is SQLite ... no
All migrations up? ... yes
Database contains orphaned UsersGroups? ... no
GitLab config exists? ... yes
GitLab config outdated? ... no
Log directory writable? ... yes
Tmp directory writable? ... yes
Init script exists? ... yes
Init script up-to-date? ... yes
```

I'm stuck at this part:

GitLab Shell version >= 1.9.6 ? ... FAIL. Please update gitlab-shell to 1.9.6 from 1.9.5

Could anybody help how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to update `gitlab-shell`, can be accomplished with the following set of commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell.git
cp config.yml.example config.yml
vim config.yml
```

> make sure you replace gitlab_url with your desired URL

```
sudo -u git -H ./bin/install
```

Note that it looks like you're doing quite a bit as root that would be better of done as user "git", hence some of the warnings you're getting.  While [this](http://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-gitlab-ruby-and-nginx-on-a-debian-7-wheezy-vps/) link is a little dated, it may be useful to help you see how to do this as user "git" rather than root.